# Can I use Bluray as a boot cd?

Tags: blu-ray

If so what is the new maximum size of a boot(blueray) cd?
Please explain the differences between boot cds and boot blueray cds if possible.

If this is not possible please explain why.

Comment: BluRay discs are 25GB (50GB double-sided): why didn't you search for `bluray disc size`? As for your main question, I remember reading about differences, possibly in BIOS firmware, but I'd have to search to find it: why don't you?

Comment: @AFH yes 25GB interesting.  I am searching but without having a computer to test with Im afraid I probably won't determine to much.

Comment: What's wrong with the computer you're using for this site?

Comment: @AFH I have no blueray drive not to mention I'm browsing the site on an iPhone.  25GB wasn't really an answer to my question.  File system restrictions prevent you from using certain things as boot cds.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a different type of medium. As long as you burn bootable ISO on it and boot it from drive which is seen by UEFI/BIOS it should work. I have several bootable BD's created using dd in Linux and/or Acronis in Windows and they normally work as expected.

As for size question, that's interesting. I believe ISO 9660 can have 2^32 blocks which is 8TiB and that's far away from current BD size ~100GB. So as long as booting is implemented properly according to ISO 9660 standard you should be theoretically able to use whole BD size. There might be problem with file size (that depends on ISO Level of interchange - Level 1,2,3 thing...) and with loaded software itself which might not be able to work with such large volume. Also not all tools for burning support unlimited (read maximum) ISO 9660 volume size.

Comment: Have you done this yourself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If you're asking if I created bootable BD myself yes I did - using Acronis and SATA BD burner (Pioneer BDR-209DBK) from which I booted it then. But none of my BDs was full, I simply burned bootable ISO that would fit DVD as well.